# MySql query to fetch data in 3rd table from 1st table

Tags: mysql

I have three tables.

1. `Fee` table which contains `Fee_id` and `Fee_name`...
2. `Session` table which contains `session_id` and `fee_id(foreign key)`.
3. `classfee_charge` table which contains `session_id(foreign key),class_id(fo[![enter image description here][1]][1]reign key) and amount.`

I have to store amount of `fee` classwise in `classfee_charge` table.

How to fetch `fee_name` in `classfee_charge` table?

Comment: Please post the image for more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the current session_id (1 in the code bellow) after you group by Fee_name to have the aggregate data for each kind of expense :

```
SELECT  
    Fee.Fee_id,
    Fee.Fee_name
FROM 
    Fee, Session
WHERE
    Fee.Fee_id = Session.Fee_id
AND 
  Session.session_id = 1
GROUP BY
  Fee.Fee_name
```

The result :

```
Fee_id  Fee_name
1   Expense
```

[SQL Fiddle for more details](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5e952/3)

Comment: I have added an image of my table ... Plz view that... Actually i have to fetch only fee name acc to my interface to enter charge in classfee_charge table.

Comment: Could you create SQL Fiddle with your data we can see what's going on ? Or just i need to see the data of the classfee_charge table

Comment: I'm sorry but its not clear to me, so for my understanding in fact you dont have data in classfee_charge table you want to implement a interface to enter your Fees for each session ?

Comment: Classfee_charge is empty... I hv to insert into that table using interface.. so u hv to fetch fee id... I hv added pic of my interface too

Comment: Bro... Actually in my interface there is a dropdown to select class and a drop down to select fee_name. I want to fetch fee_name using session_id so that it can be display in the dropdown and then after clicking on add... The session_id which belongs to that fee and amount will get inserted in classfee_charge.

Comment: So happy to help you just mark it as solution to the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT f.Fee_name from fee f
INNER join session s
on s.Fee_id=f.Fee_id
INNER join classfee_charge cf
on cf.session_id=s.session_id

Comment: The above query gives result as empty set . 